# Why can a derived class call base class constructor twice?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I am learning about multiple inheritance and the diamond problem, but I'm confused as to why a base class constructor can be called twice without a compiler error in the first place.

Example from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiple-inheritance-in-c/

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class Person { 
   // Data members of person  
public: 
    Person(int x)  { cout << "Person::Person(int ) called" << endl;   } 
    int y;                                                               \\ <- I added this
}; 

class Faculty : public Person { 
   // data members of Faculty 
public: 
    Faculty(int x):Person(x)   { 
       cout<<"Faculty::Faculty(int ) called"<< endl; 
    } 
}; 

class Student : public Person { 
   // data members of Student 
public: 
    Student(int x):Person(x) { 
        cout<<"Student::Student(int ) called"<< endl; 
    } 
}; 

class TA : public Faculty, public Student  { 
public: 
    TA(int x):Student(x), Faculty(x)   { 
        cout<<"TA::TA(int ) called"<< endl; 
    } 
}; 

int main()  { 
    TA ta1(30); 
}
```

Output:

```
Person::Person(int ) called
Faculty::Faculty(int ) called
Person::Person(int ) called
Student::Student(int ) called
TA::TA(int ) called
```

Since the derived class `TA` calls the `Person` constructor twice, doesn't that mean `TA` would have two copies of data members that have the same name, for example two instances of `int y`?

Comment: `TA` has indeed two bases `Person`. It is not a diamond inheritance, but more a Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing from link is misleading, it is not a diamond, but more a Y:

```
 ----------    ----------
|  Person  |  |  Person  |
 ----------    ----------
      ^             ^
      |             |
 ----------    ----------
|  Student |  |  Faculty |
 ----------    ----------
      ^             ^
      |             |
       \-----   ----/
             \ /
              |
         ----------
        |    TA    |
         ----------
```

And yes you have two copies of member of `Person` (`Student::y` and `Faculty::y`).

With virtual inheritance, you have a diamond with only one unique `Person`.

Comment: why is it not a compile time error to have two copies of the same members with the same exact name from Person, since the Person constructor is called twice?

Comment: Why forbid it? If you use composition instead of inheritance, you might also have twice the same member type.

Comment: I'm just thinking if I created a class with two member variables with the same name, I would get a compiler error for redeclaring

Comment: One is `Student::y` and the other is `Faculty::y`. as facility, we might use base class member name when not ambiguous.

Comment: so when you make the point about it being more of a Y instead of a diamond, is that a criticism of the name of the "diamond problem"?

Comment: @csguy As I read it, that is not a criticism of the name "diamond problem", but rather a declaration that the name does not apply to your example. In your example, each `TA` object contains two `y` fields; not a diamond. If you were to have only one `y` field (which requires a virtual base class), then you would have a diamond. (Follow your link, and look at the picture showing the diamond problem. Pay close attention to the note at the bottom: *"Name and Age needed only once"*. That's key to diamond inheritance.)

Comment: @JaMiT i don't think i fully understand, are you saying that my example is not a diamond (it is what needs to be solved) and that when the diamond problem is solved, the solution looks like a diamond? (the problem is in Y form, solution is diamond form which is achieved with virtual)

Comment: @csguy Correct, "the name ['diamond problem'] does not apply to your example" means that your example is not a diamond. As for the rest, I don't understand what you are trying to say. Maybe things will make more sense after you've learned more about the diamond problem.

Comment: @csguy: I see the *diamond problem* as *"How to create one unique Grand father base class?"* or *"How to create a diamond hierarchy?"*. The diamond is not the problem but the target. And the regular multiple inheritance leads to *Y* instead of diamond. Solution is to use *virtual inheritance*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the integer argument, try printing the address of the member variable instead.  Then try it with virtual inheritance, it should give a better idea what's going on.

```
std::cout << &y << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try investigating the size of the TA object you instantiate. What does the size tell you? What size would you expect for the case of a single copy of Person? For two copies?

Try actually accessing the y attribute and see if you get a compiler error!

Comment: size of structure is not trivial, (especially with polymorphic type, virtual inheritance, potential EBO (Empty base optimisation).